# Data Grid and Angular

Tags: angular, datagrid

we are evaluating to migrate an windows app to Angular/SPA.
The future app will be develop to be use on desktop because we need a lot of data inserted by keyboard.

The first question: there's any sense to migrate an windows app that, at the end, will be run always on a desktop.
The second question: there's an angular component similar a datagrid? the datagrid is the main component that user interact so, we need insert data directly from datagrid and ability to sort and context menu.

Best regards.